# How do you change the Play 2.1! Framework session cookie name

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

How do I configure the namne of the SESSION cookie in Play 2.1?

By default Play seems to create a cookie called 'PLAY_SESSION'. How can I customise the name?

Thanks

Comment: Don't downvote this question, it's correct and has sense!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All of the details about the session can be configured within the

> application.conf

The setting you want is

> session.cookieName=**COOKIE_NAME**

Its worth looking at the Docs within the Http.scala file. Mainly around the Session case class.

Hope that helps!